# Streamlit example works oke in virtual conda env but my test app doesn't

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, streamlit

I am trying to get Streamlit work for two days now, but it's time to get your help!

I am working on windows10 env. I have newest version of Annaconda installed.

I have created a virtual environment, this works:

[image]

The build in Hello script works in my test1 virtual env:
[image]

Trying to run my own testscript, just containing: import streamlit as st, gives this result:

[image]

This is a valid Python script:

[image]

The script is stored within my virt env:
[image]

I stored it in the hello folder as well, for test reasons:

[image]

Hopefully someone has an idea what could be wrong (with installation or with me....).
THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

found 'answer' myself: for some reason I have to give in the entire path to the python file (while the file is in the virt env itself).

For others looking for an answer to the same problem:

1: create virtual environment (I used Conda, see above) with Python installation.
2: activate it.
3: install streamlit, numpy, pandas etc
4: create a simple first .py script with streamlit elements, for example:

'''

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import streamlit as st

x = st.slider('Select a value')
```

'''

5: save this .py script.
6: run the script from your conda virt env terminal by typing:
'''

```
streamlit run C:\Users\Gebruiker\Anaconda3\envs\test3\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\test\streamtest1.py
```

'''
(of course this is mine path in this case).
7: hit enter and voila: it works!

greetings Jan